# Adding Spinner View in Android without using an XML layout

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to create a spinner in my code without using an xml layout at all. It seems that you need an ArrayAdapter with the spinner but the constructors all want a resource id in its set of constructors. Well, when not using XML layout i dont see how I can get a resource id.

```
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);

        List<String> spinnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerList.add("Ice Cream Sandwich");
        spinnerList.add("Hushpuppies");
        spinnerList.add("Pickled Pigs Feet");
        spinnerList.add("Cupcakes");
        spinnerList.add("Chocolate Covered Pretzels");

        ArrayAdapter<String> mySpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, ??);

        //spinner.setAdapter(mySpinnerAdapter);
```

how should i instantiate an ArrayAdapter here? thanks all in advance and hopefully i didn't make anyone too hungry. :)

EDIT: i think i have it now - will test and see...

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> mySpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
 mySpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spinner.setAdapter(mySpinnerAdapter);
```

Comment: my edit did it but i am confused about how a android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item equates to a resourceID. can anyone add to this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was able to use the android.R.layout and a subclass to solve what i needed to here

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Spinner comboAutos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCarros);
            comboAutos.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MyActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list));`

where list is a `List<String>`list with the values that you want :)

Hope it helps you!